# How do I run Windows 8 via virtualization?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

I would like to run Windows 8 within a virtual machine under Ubuntu.

My quick attempt with VMware failed.

Has anyone reached to run Windows 8 on Ubuntu?

ps: Microsoft just released a public preview of Windows 8 -- see http://dev.windows.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualbox didn't work for me, but VMWare did.
See http://www.mywindowsclub.com/resources/5081-Install-Windows-VMWare-Workstation.aspx 
make sure to enable hardware virtualization in your BIOS

Comment: Broken link. It seems that the article was moved here: http://www.techulator.com/resources/5081-Install-Windows-VMWare-Workstation.aspx although the instructions are for windows :(

Answer (score 5):

Will work with Virtualbox. You have to enable hardware virtualization in the settings, VT-x and Nested Paging.

Comment: You may also have to enable IO APIC.

Comment: Also if installing to an ssd, ensure you tick the Solid State Drive box under the hard disk configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Try qemu with 512 MB ram.. by the way before going further check MD5 sum matches the checksum provided by Microsoft. There is a probability that the iso you downloaded is corrupt.

Comment: Why 512MB ram? These are the requirements: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor

1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)

16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)

Comment: do check your facts, and don't tell me that you can not install windows 7 on 256 MB of ram because I have installed one on my old machine. these system requirements are advised requirements not actual.
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/windows-8-interesting-competition/

Comment: Wasn't my intention to piss you off man, just chill! I know it's possible to run Windows7 with lower requirements, but this is W8 and why not go with the recommended requirements? Especially when the user is having issues running it...